# Java: Open default mail client

Tags: java, email

I have a software that periodically parses my mail inbox. The functionallity of the program depends on the default mail program running.

How can I start the default mail program from within java?

I know that you can acheive this by using the `Desktop` class:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().mail()
```

but in addition to starting the default mail client it also opens a new email window which I don't want.
How do I open the default mail client without opening a "Compose a new EMail" window?

**Edit:** I'm trying to extract the information myselve now using this code snippet: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180233/en-us but since this code doesn't compile (like most of the microsoft code snippets, which is really bad when you aren't a C++ developer and just need some code) because it's missing the reference to `&lpProfileTable`. How would the missing code look like?

Comment: I really dont want to use JNI but I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the MSDN Sample should look like:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT

#include <windows.h>
#include <mapix.h>

#include <iostream>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hinstPrev,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    // Get a IProfAdmin Interface.
    LPPROFADMIN lpProfAdmin;
    HRESULT hr = MAPIAdminProfiles(0, &lpProfAdmin);

    // Get the Table of Profiles
    LPMAPITABLE lpProfileTable;
    hr = lpProfAdmin->GetProfileTable(0, &lpProfileTable);

    // Build a restriction where PR_DEFAULT_PROFILE = TRUE
    SPropValue spvDefaultProfile;
    spvDefaultProfile.ulPropTag = PR_DEFAULT_PROFILE;
    spvDefaultProfile.Value.b = TRUE;

    SRestriction sres;
    sres.rt = RES_PROPERTY;
    sres.res.resProperty.relop = RELOP_EQ;
    sres.res.resProperty.ulPropTag = PR_DEFAULT_PROFILE;
    sres.res.resProperty.lpProp = &spvDefaultProfile;

    hr = lpProfileTable->Restrict(&sres, TBL_BATCH);
    hr = lpProfileTable->FindRow(&sres, BOOKMARK_BEGINNING, 0);

    LPSRowSet pRow = NULL;
    hr = lpProfileTable->QueryRows(1, 0, &pRow);
     // We have a match
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        LPSTR lpDisplayName = pRow->aRow[0].lpProps[0].Value.lpszA;
        std::cout << lpDisplayName;
    }
}
```

It compiles under g++, but I cannot figure out how to link the executable...

Comment: Thank you a lot! The value of lpDisplayName is "Default". When I parse this as the profilename to the MAPILogonEx function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815545.aspx) I get an error that the profile doesn't exist. I already tried before to supply the fucntion with the String "Default" and it didn't work. I had hopped to get the correct value to parse from the posted code. How could I do that? See my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561415/c-mapi-mapilogonex-how-to-open-default-mail-inbox

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with this API and I cannot make it run in order to test it, sorry...