# C++ MAPI: MAPILogonEx, how to open default mail inbox?

Tags: c++, email, mapi

I want to login to my default mail inbox via:

```
MAPILogonEx(0, profileName, NULL, MAPI_LOGON_UI, &lpMAPISession)
```

where I defined profileName as:

```
LPTSTR profileName = _T("Default");
```

However this doesn't work and tells me that I supplied an invalid profilename.

What would be the correct value for the variable profileName to login to the default mail inbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually really easy once you know... but you can also waste half a day on it..

Just call:
`MAPILogonEx(0, 0, NULL, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_USE_DEFAULT , &lpMAPISession);`

I'm still unable to supply a profilename but the default one will do the trick for now.